ADCS - How to keep the history of the pending certificate request
From the web interface of my ADCS, I would like to keep the history of certificate requests that are in "View the status of a pending certificate request".
After closing the interface page, if I reopen it, I no longer see the history. I can't see my ongoing requests, approved requests, or denied requests. This is inconvenient because I can't check if my request has been approved or not, and I can't retrieve the issued certificate.
The only way to see it is to keep the interface open until it is approved by an admin and retrieve it directly. But if I accidentally close the page, it is no longer possible.
I have tried various options in ADCS and IIS, but nothing seems to work. I have attempted different configurations and settings, but I am still unable to retain the history of certificate requests in the ADCS web interface.

You should enable auditing on AD Certification Authority Console - CA Properties. Then the certificate requests will be logged in detail in the Security Event Log. You can then backup event logs and this will include CA certificate requests. As security logs may fill up quickly, backup schedule should be modified accordingly.

Thanks you, it works. But is there a way to make it appear in the ADCS web interface ? Because I leave access to the interface to users, I doubt they know how to manipulate the Security Event Log. Ideally, they will have access to it directly on the page.

Pls chk https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-cs/request-certificate-windows-server  "Request a certificate using Certification Authority Web Enrollment" page.  Server event logs and audits normally not viewable by end users.
